# bad value for range (ArgumentError) in ruby

Tags: ruby

I get the desired output but the interpreter throws an ArgumentError-bad value for range ?

Q)Given an array of integers, for each integer output all integers from 1 to that integer; e.g. if the integer was 5, you would output 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Solution:

```
numbers = [7, 3, 5, 2, 1, 8, 4]

counter = 0
loop do
  num = numbers[counter]
  (1..num).each do |ele|
    puts ele 

  end 

  counter += 1

end
```

Comment: (1) Your loop never terminates. (2) What is `num` when `counter` reaches `7`? (3) `loop` is almost never used in Ruby, you almost always use something out of `Enumerable` (such as `each`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'll let someone else explain why your code is broken, except to say that unless this is a classroom exercise (in which case ask your instructor what the point is), the code is not really idiomatic Ruby. Aside from being more complicated than it needs to be, non-idiomatic Ruby is often harder to debug. One of the following examples will do the right thing when using Ruby 3.0.1, and both are much shorter and less error-prone that manually iterating:

```rb
    # if you just want to print each item
    numbers = [7, 3, 5, 2, 1, 8, 4]
    numbers.each { puts _1 }
```

```rb
    # if you want to print each slice of length n
    numbers.each_index do
      next unless _1 > 0
      p numbers.slice 0, _1
    end
```

If you need your output in a specific format, that wasn't defined in your original question. Both of these options can be modified to suit whatever output format you're looking for.